# Javascript - how to loop through dict inside a list

Tags: javascript, for-loop

So I am pretty new when it comes to Javascript and it is as simple as read a json list with a value of:

```
{
    "URL": [{
            "https://testing.com/en/p/-12332423/": "999"
        }, {
            "https://testing.com/en/p/-123456/": "123"
        },
        {
            "https://testing.com/en/p/-456436346/": "422"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I would like to do is to have both the URL and the amount of numbers etc

`"https://testing.com/en/p/-12332423/"` and `"999"`

and I would like to for loop so it runs each "site" one by one so the first loop should be

`"https://testing.com/en/p/-12332423/"` and `"999"`

second loop should be:

`"https://testing.com/en/p/-123456/"` and `"123"`

and so on depending on whats inside the json basically.

So my question is how am I able to loop it so I can use those values for each loop?

Comment: You can use `Object.entries()` --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: Do you want to test every key with every value or just every url?

Comment: @AdamOrlov Checking it right now, Might not even need a list in that case.

Comment: @Wimanicesir I would like to do both key and value :)

Comment: @AdamOrlov I actually used your Object.entries and it worked very very well. You should put it up as the answer.

Comment: @Hellosiroverthere thats fine, glad it worked ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const data = {
  "URL": [
    {"https://testing.com/en/p/-12332423/": "999"}, 
    {"https://testing.com/en/p/-123456/": "123"},
    {"https://testing.com/en/p/-456436346/": "422"}
  ]
}

data.URL.forEach(obj => { // loop
  const [url, num] = Object.entries(obj)[0]; // grab the key and value from each entry - note the [0]
  console.log("Url",url,"Number", num); // do something with them
})
```

Answer (score 2):

As Adam Orlov pointed out in the coment, `Object.entries()` can be very useful here.

```js
const URLobj = {
    "URL": [{
            "https://testing.com/en/p/-12332423/": "999"
        }, {
            "https://testing.com/en/p/-123456/": "123"
        },
        {
            "https://testing.com/en/p/-456436346/": "422"
        }
    ]
};

URLobj.URL.forEach(ob => {
   console.log('ob', ob);
   const entries = Object.entries(ob)[0]; // 0 just means the first key-value pair, but because each object has only one we can just use the first one
   const url = entries[0];
   const number = entries[1];
   console.log('url', url);
   console.log('number', number);
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this method and it worked very well! :)

Answer (score 1):

let's call your object o1 for simplicity. So you can really go to town with this link - https://zellwk.com/blog/looping-through-js-objects/

or you can just use this code :

```
for(var i = 0; i < o1.URL.length; i++) {
//each entry
var site = Object.keys(URL[i]) [0];
var value = Object.values(URL[i]) [0];
// ... do whatever
}
```

don't forget each member of the array is an object (key : value) in its own right

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the keys and their values into another object array using map

Then use the for loop on the newly created array. You can use this method on any object to separate their keys and values into another object array.

```js
const data = {
  "URL": [{
      "https://testing.com/en/p/-12332423/": "999"
    }, {
      "https://testing.com/en/p/-123456/": "123"
    },
    {
      "https://testing.com/en/p/-456436346/": "422"
    }
  ]
}

var extracted = data.URL.map(e => ({
  url: Object.keys(e)[0],
  number: Object.values(e)[0]
}))

extracted.forEach((e) => console.log(e))
```

Comment: Why are you extracting the key and values into a new object? Just to name them? If so, why not destruct instead?

Comment: Yeah thats right, just if the same array could be of help somewhere else in the program... I agree that it's not necessary.

Comment: I have a feeling from the question that map(..) and destruct(s) are pretty advanced for the asker @mplungjan. I think he was trying to keep it short and simple. You are right though. Cleaner code is better.

Comment: Object.keys AND Object.values creates two new objects to iterate. You already used map, destructing is a lovely think to learn early :)